# Why won't my comparative if statement of two variables work?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, state, command-pattern

In the following piece of code, once executed, it will change the state `diet` of an object `hek` based on a random number generator. I also have an `undo()` function which works perfectly fine in run-time.

What I am trying to do is: When the state of the object is changed but, the previous state `prevDiet` is equal to the changed state `currentDiet`, I want the program to call `undo()`.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class changeDietCom implements Command {

    Hek hek;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int x;
    DietBehaviour prevDiet;
    DietBehaviour currentDiet;

    public changeDietCom(Hek hek) {
        this.hek = hek;
    }

    public void execute() {

        x = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;

        prevDiet = hek.getDietBehaviour();
        if (x == 1) {

            hek.setDietBehaviour(new Enemies());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hek's diet has been changed!", "Changing diet", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            currentDiet = hek.getDietBehaviour();
            hek.performDiet();

            if (prevDiet == currentDiet) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Diet hasn't changed!", "Current Diet = Prev Diet", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                undo();
            }
        }
        else if (x == 2) {

            hek.setDietBehaviour(new ArmouredKnights());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hek's diet has been changed!", "Changing diet", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            currentDiet = hek.getDietBehaviour();
            hek.performDiet();

            if (prevDiet == currentDiet) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Diet hasn't changed!", "Current Diet = Prev Diet", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                undo();
            }
        }
        else if (x == 3) {

            hek.setDietBehaviour(new BigMac());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hek's diet has been changed!", "Changing diet", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            currentDiet = hek.getDietBehaviour();
            hek.performDiet();

            if (prevDiet == currentDiet) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Diet hasn't changed!", "Current Diet = Prev Diet", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                undo();
            }
        }
    }

    public void undo() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Undoing diet change...", "Undoing Diet Change", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        hek.setDietBehaviour(prevDiet);
        hek.performDiet();
    }
}
```

But whenever both the previous state `prevDiet` and the current state `currentDiet` are equal to each other during run-time the `if` statement doesn't return true, and I can't see why not? Could someone please maybe shed some light as to why and how I can fix this?

I should mention that I am using the command pattern for the design of this part of the program.

Comment: have you tried prevDiet.equals(currentDiet) ?

Comment: It looks like you're new here, you should know that If an answer works for you its courteous to accept and upvote, if it doesn't work you may be able to comment on it and it will be altered or explained for you.

Comment: This answered was useful, but didn't solve my problem. `DietBehaviour` is an interface that I have implemented from and not a concrete class so I'm confused when people are pointing out that I should override the `equals()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DietBehavior` objects are object types, so you can't use `==` to compare them. What you want to use is `.equals()`. If `DietBehavior` is your own class then you will have to implement the method, but its pretty simple.

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
// compare them here based on instance variables
}
```

Comment: The argument for `equals` must be an `Object`, not a `DietBehaviour`.

Comment: @Manu edited, thank you

Comment: DietBehaviour is an interface and not a class, so I'm not really sure how I would go about that?

Comment: @PureShpongled `getDietBehavior()` must return an object though and you need a class to have an object, so there must be a class that implements `DietBehavior`. Can you alter that class?

Comment: Ah! I see, go through the the classes which implement the interface, i.e. `ArmouredKnights()`, `BigMacs()` and `Enemies()`, and alter each `equals()` method of said objects?

Comment: Yes if you implement `.equals()` correctly and then use it instead of `==` that should work.

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally have it fixed! You guys are awesome!

Comment: @PureShpongled no problem, please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

With `if (prevDiet == currentDiet) {`, you compare object references instead of the actual values. Use `if (prevDiet.equals(currentDiet)) {` instead, and make sure you override the `equals()` method of `DietBehaviour`.

Note that when you override `equals()`, you should also override `hashCode()` and the implementations should be consistent. More information about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).